# Export DataPump - ORA-01555 Snapshot too old

Tags: oracle-12c, export, expdp

I'm trying to export a customer's production database (schema) for problem solving.

During export, I'm getting the following:

```
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 97.83 GB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-31693: Table data object "SCHEMA"."PROBLEMTABLE" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 1 with name "_SYSSMU1_1522693822$" too small
```

The table is just over 5GB  (not the largest) but is heavily used 24x7.

Undo retention is set at 900s and, as this is an Amazon RDS instance, I cannot make changes to the parameter option group.

I've tried a number of different options during export - trying to force CONSISTENT=N for example but that didn't work.

The table does not need to be consistent to a specific time, as long as the data contained is approximately similar to the time  the rest of the schema was exported then that's acceptable.

Is there another way to handle this in the export command, or would this be better if I exported that specific table first (there are no constraints/dependencies on this object), and then ran the schema export again excluding the table in question?

Comment: Batch your export?

Comment: When you say Batch, do you mean break it up into pieces (so problematic table first, followed by the rest in a separate execution)?

Comment: yes, break the job up into manageable chunks so that the ORA-01555 can't occur!

Comment: I've tried exporting just that specific table but still run into the ORA-01555 error

Comment: OK then - split it in two? Or maybe investigate your settings? What triggers ORA-01555? Can you temporarily disable logging or whatever causes it? Since all you're doing is a copy and not an any change of data, I **think** you should **probably** be able to reduce any transactional overhead using a/some setting(s)?

Comment: Try here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:275215756923 - and also look at UNDO_RETENTION?